# Interbase server returns an error "Column unknown"

Tags: sql, interbase

this sql-code returns error only on Interbase 2020 server (on Firebird 3 works properly):

> Error at line 1. Dynamic SQL Error: Error at line 1. sql error
> code=-206. Column unknown INC.

```
select                                                                          
      Goods_id,
      coalesce(sum(inc),0) as incomes,
      coalesce(sum(sale),0) as sales,
      coalesce(sum(writeoff),0) as writeoff,
      sum(coalesce(inc,0)-coalesce(sale,0)-coalesce(writeoff,0)) as endqnt
    from(
        select 
            i.goods_id, 
            sum(i.qty) as inc,
            cast(0 as float) as sale,
            cast(0 as float) as writeoff
        from income i
        where cast(i.recdate as date) <= :d  
        group by i.goods_id  
     union all
        select 
            s.goods_id, 
            cast(0 as float),
            sum(s.qty) as sale,
            cast(0 as float)
         from sales s
         where cast(s.recdate as date) <= :d 
         group by s.goods_id    
     union all
        select
            w.goods_id,
            cast(0 as float), 
            cast(0 as float),
            sum(w.Qty)  as writeoff, 
        from writeoff w
        where cast(i.recdate as date) <= :d   
    group by w.goods_id) 
   group by  goods_id
```

How correct this code for Interbase 2020 server?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

1. adding 'as inc' to second and third subquery columns i.e "cast(0 as float) as inc"
2. Simplify the query by removing the subqueries (until you're not using union all) and see if it works or error changes

Comment: bzelbob, sorry for the late reply. strange behavior: each 3 subquery separately works correctly but together ( select... union all select.... union all select ... union all) gives an error  'data type unknown'.  I tried use coalesce but it seams sum function in coalesce in interbase isn't supported (error: expression evalution not supported).  :(